# Measuring length of curved lines for district

Tags: line, curved

I work in a country which is divided in election destricts(polygon shp). I have the roads of the country as a vector layer (vector shp).

I want to find a tool for QGIS like sum line lengths of qgis (perhaps a plug-in) to do the same work as the above-mentioned one but only for the curved lines of roads not the straight lines or the opposite. I use either ArcGis or QGis.

Comment: You will need to provide much more information about the format and what you have tried.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: For same origin and destination, a straight line should have lower length that the curved ones. Consider adding a screenshot of the study area.